# How to deal with unstable 3rd party object tree (sorry, I can’t come up with a better title)?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

Let’s say I have to use an unstable assembly that I cannot refractor. My code is supposed to be the client of a `CustomerCollection` that is (surprise) a collection of `Customer` instances. Each customer instance has further properties like a collection of `Order` instances. I hope you get the idea.

Since the assembly behaves not that well my approach is to wrap each class in a façade where I can deal with exceptions and workarounds an all that stuff. (To make things more complicated I like to design the wrapper to be usable with WPF regarding data binding.)

So my question is about the design of the wrapper, e.g. `CustomerCollectionFacade`. How to expose the object tree (customers, orders, properties of orders)? Is the `CustomerWrapper` collection stored in a field or do I create `CustomerWrapper` instances on the fly (in the get accessor of a property maybe)?

Any ideas welcome. Thanks!

**Edit:**
Unfortunately the way proposed by krosenvold is not an option in my case. Since the object tree’s behavior is very interactive (editing from multiple views, events fired if properties change) I will not opt to abandon the ‘source object’. These changes are supposed to propagate to the source. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I generally try to isolate such transformations into one or more adapter classes and let them do the whole story at once. This is a god idea because it is easily testable, all the conversion logic ends up in one place, and you avoid littering the conversion logic "all over the place".

Sometimes there is state in the underlying (source) object that is going to be needed when/if you're updating the object. You might not be exposing this data in your cleaned-up api, so it's going to have to be hidden somewhere.

If you choose to encapsulate the original object there's always the chance that someone'll break that encapsulation sometime in the future and start leaking the gory details of the underlying object. That reason alone is usually enough for me to not keep a reference to the original instance, since I actually understand what I'm doing six months later when I'm in a hurry. But if you keep it somewhere else you'll need lifecycle management for the originals, so I usually end up stashing it away in some secret interface on the "clean" object.